# Getting raw results from Django Haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have site using Django Haystack (with the Whoosh backend). I would like to be able to get all results for a given model matching a given query. Something like

```
from haystack import get_results

result_list = get_results(model=MyModel, query='foo')
```

In the documentation I have found a lot of stuff about customizing the default views and forms, advanced searching and so on, but I cannot find anything for the simple task of getting all the models matching a query and managing them on my own. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SearchQuerySet](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.6/searchquery_api.html). For example:

```
In [1]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

In [2]: SearchQuerySet().filter(content='abra')
Out[2]: [<SearchResult: art.artist (pk=u'23')>, <SearchResult: art.artwork (pk=u'191')>]

In [3]: SearchQuerySet().filter(content='abra').count()
Out[3]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SearchQuerySet like : -

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(content='abra').models(MyModel)
```

It will only return result from **MyModel** model.